# Activity Start when using just audio background plugin

Tags: just-audio

We're using just audio and just audio background for our Flutter music app. When you add just_audio_background plugin you are required to change the launcher activity name to 'com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity'

As this is a launcher activity we want to start the activity in a custom notification implementation like below but it gives an error.

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
```

We also tried below but it throws classNotFoundException at startup

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Class.forName("com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity")));
```

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623653/com-ryanheise-audioservice-audioserviceactivity-cannot-be-cast-to-androidx-fragm